# How do I do this without an expensive firewall?

Tags: security, networking, firewall

I've got a cheap-o Motorola Cable Modem for now and I hate it. I'm used to doing this with SonicWALL routers but life happened. I need a way to isolate these groups securely and keep threats from crossing those circle boundaries. The PowerConnect switch is fully managed I just forgot the IP and forgot how the heck to connect to that.

I can use Linux/Unix on a few computers only. Am I screwed unless I buy hardware and by that I mean good hardware with SPI, DPI and IPS?

- Blue = Active Directory Connection
- Purple = Printer, NAS connection.
- Black = Network connection.

Probably confusing as hell.

[Here's an link to view the below image full size](http://www.pdotorg.org/networkmap.jpg)

[image: http://www.pdotorg.org/networkmap.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

[IPCop](http://www.ipcop.org/) can accomplish everything you are looking for.  Setup an old computer with as many NICs as you have zones.  If you don't have this, you could find  cheap old computer for 50 bucks or less on craigslist and get some 10/100 NICs for cheap on Ebay.

Then you might need a separate wireless router to separate the wireless out from the wired connections.

Finally, install IPcop, setup as your heart desires, and voila, your dream come true!

As a note, IPcop stands in between you cable modem and your switch.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I tried [untangle](http://www.untangle.com/).Almost all the things needed for me was there. hope this will also help you.